# How to enable/implement HTML5-JS FileAPI functions on OSX-WebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, html, macos, webview

I have subclassed WebView and some HTML5/FileAPI functions don't work. There is no error message, no crash, nothing.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ shows you a (complete?) list of the HTML5 FileAPI interfaces: File, FileList and Blob.

There are 5 working examples:

1. Selecting a file.
2. Dropping a file.
3. Selecting multiple files (images) and rendering them.
4. Slicing a file.
5. Monitoring the progress of a load.

The first two test cases are passed without problems.
On the third one, I get to see a message saying "X files". But the images are not rendered.
Fourth and fifth don't work at all.

This only happens on OSX-WebView, on Safari everything works fine.

This code gets called when selecting files:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender
runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener:(id<WebOpenPanelResultListener>)resultListener
allowMultipleFiles:(BOOL)allowMultipleFiles
{
    NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    // Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
    [openPanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];

    // Enable the selection of directories in the dialog.
    [openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];

    // Allow multiple files
    [openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:allowMultipleFiles];

    [openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        if (NSOKButton == result) {
//            [resultListener chooseFilenames:[openPanel URLs]];
            NSArray* URLs = [openPanel URLs];
            NSMutableArray *files = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (int i = 0; i <[URLs count]; i++) {
                NSString *filename = [[URLs objectAtIndex:i]relativePath];
                [files addObject:filename];
            }
            [resultListener chooseFilenames:files];
        }else
            [resultListener cancel];
    }];
}
```

Any idea what I have to do to make my WebView  behave as Safari?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to make a pure javascript and make a connection between it and objective-c? You can use something like https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge

Comment: @TareqEl-Masri I haven't, but seems I'll need to implemente FileReader, Blob and so on, then use a JS bridge. (as you said).

Comment: I'm really interested, tell me if it worked